# How to remove horizontal space in stacked ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot, R produces a horizontal space in my stacked graph if the figure is to wide.

Desired Output:
[image]

What I currently get:
[image]

Reszing the figure helps but it should be a wider.

The code I am using:

```
ggplot(melt(portfolios), aes(x=variable, y=value)) + 
  geom_area(aes(colour = portfolio, fill= portfolio), position = 'stack') +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  geom_line(aes(y=0))

Excerpt of the DataFrame (melt(portfolios)):
      portfolio variable value
   1:         1        1   123
   2:         2        1   131
   3:         3        1   116
   4:         4        1   142
   5:         5        1   141
  ---                         
6996:         6      700   251
```

Comment: What is the melt function you're using and how is it working in your code? Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: The given excerpt is already the melted DF!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use `geom_bar()` with `width = 1`?

```
library(ggplot2)

portfolios <- data.frame(portfolio = rep(1:10, each = 100), variable = 1:100, value = runif(1000))

ggplot(portfolios, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill = factor(portfolio))) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity", width = 1) +
  #geom_area(aes(colour = portfolio, fill= portfolio), position = 'stack') +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  geom_line(aes(y=0))
```

Yields:

[image]